# Why write() console output returns a character

Tags: java

Meddling with the low level method write() in java and came across this confusing piece of code.

```
int b;

b = 'X';
System.out.write(b);
```

The method in its general documented form  would be`void write(int byteval)`

I understand byte and int can be assigned due to automatic type conversion but why does`write()` output characters despite being declared `int` ? I know its not commonly used but still curious why only the low-order 8 bits are written to allow this.

Comment: [JLS-4.2.1. Integral Types and Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1)

Comment: We can only guess why the method was initially defined with an `int` instead of a `byte` parameter. One reason may be that a `byte` parameter requires a lot of type casts, e.g. one would have to use `os.write((byte)0)` to write a zero byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [`ASCII`](http://www.asciitable.com/) table. Note that passing `char` to `int` makes conversion according to the ASCII table. The range of `char` is between 0 and 65535. The character `'X'` is converted to integer number value of `88`. So:

```
int b = 'X';
System.out.println(b); // 88
```

The method [`System.out::write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#write-int-) works a bit different than `System.out::println` from a snippet above, because it accepts `int` as argument and print's its value according to the ASCII table. Its documentation says:

> Writes the specified byte to this stream. If the byte is a newline and automatic flushing is enabled then the flush method will be invoked.
>
> Note that the byte is written as given; to write a character that will be translated according to the platform's default character encoding, use the print(char) or println(char) methods.

Comment: Java doesn't use ASCII. See [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) and [UTF-16](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-1) as referenced in Java documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to recognize all the **actors and their roles**.

Java: [`PrintStream.write(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#write-int-) "the byte is written as given". In this case, it writes to the [`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) stream. "Typically this stream corresponds to display output or another output destination specified by the host environment or user."

*There is no character encoding (and therefore, no text) at this point.*

If you have agreed with your users that they should interpret the output of the program as text, then you must also have agreed on a character encoding. Very often, a program that writes to the output stream is run in a terminal (aka console). Any a point in time, for a user, on a machine, the terminal is configured to use a specific character encoding. (Linux `locale`; Windows `chcp`.) [A lot of people overlook this step because for most common Western characters there is a lot of similarity between character encodings.]

It is also common to "pipe" (aka redirect) program output to a file or the input stream of another program. There still must be an agreement as the format and purpose of the output. Many text editors, when opening a file as text, "detect" (guess) at a character encoding and often display it to the user. It's up to the user to tell the text editor to use the correct character encoding.

The text editor may "detect" the smallest and/or most likely character encoding among many possibilities. This is often confusing to users who think the text editor is telling them what the character encoding is, instead of the other way around. Sometimes the guess is good enough for reading the current contents of the file. However, if the user were to add new characters using the wrong character encoding, then the expectation of the program author is broken.

To summarize the actors and their roles are:

- program and library: write bytes (at least in the code you've written)
- program author: **communicate intent and format of output, especially character encoding if applicable**
- user: configure terminal or downstream program to use the same character encoding
- user: correct text editor's guessed encoding if wrong